# EnableCorsAttribute not working but seems to be configured?

Tags: c#, angular, cors, asp.net-web-api2

I've enabled CORS in my Web API 2 app in WebApiConfig.cs file like this:

```
// enable cors
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

However, I'm still getting the following error from my Angular 5 app:

```
"Failed to load http://localhost:52056/api/v1/users/search/: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401."
```

My Angular service is pretty basic:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { User } from './user.ts';

const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  public search(userSearchRequest) : User[]{

      var userSearchUrl = "http://localhost:52056/api/v1/users/search/";
      return this.http.post<UserSearchRequest>(userSearchUrl, userSearchRequest, httpOptions );
  }
}
```

Any idea what I may need to do in order to sidestep this error?

Answer (score 1):

You get this error becuse you haven't set cors for preflight requests. I had the same issue when I was setting tokens, and this is how I solved this:
1. In NuGet Packages I have installed: `"Microsoft.Owin.Cors"`
2. In my config file `"APP_START/starup.cs"` I added:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            //*enable cors*//
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
    }
```

[Here](https://hgminerva.wordpress.com/2016/05/26/having-problem-with-pre-flight-cors-request-with-your-angular-2-app-and-web-api-2/) you can find more about thids issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to register CORS globally for all controllers then I reccomend adding this block to the Global.asax.cs file. And of course modify it to your needs.

```
   protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod != "OPTIONS") return;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, Authorization ");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End(); 
   }
```